# How to define a logout script for the Cygwin/X X Server

Tags: bash, cygwin, logout, x11

Is there a way to define a logout script for the Cygwin/X X Server?  I'm looking for something like .bash_logout, but only run when the Cygwin/X X Server shuts down.  I'm using .startxwinrc to start programs when the X server *starts*, but I haven't found something similar for when it *shuts down*.  Any ideas?

Comment: how exactly are you starting X (whats the shortcut pointing to if using a shortcut)?

Answer (score 0):

I am Assuming you are starting with startxwin.exe
I am also assuming that you would like to keep the multiwindow option set

multiwindow uses an internal window manager and so one cannot use the xinitrc script to plant a post-window manager command.

I can think of 2/3 options:

1. Create an executable wrapper to XWin (renaming XWin.exe to XWinOrig.exe then calling it from your new executable.  Note  I don't think a script would work here
2. Create your own launch script, but then you need to wither run it with 'run' and leave the 'run' icon, in which case you might as well ''sacrifice'' a bash window ... which is crappy IMO.
3. You may take # 2 and register the script with cygrunsrv

If you do use #2 or #3 - you want to pass XWin the following params `:0 -multiwin`